# Issues with signals in django

Tags: python, django, model, signals, handlers

I am using signals to send a mail and is working fine(right now I am testing it and providing the static email address). But I want to use Dynamic values of model fields in my mail function.

**e.g.** If admin changes anything from admin dashboard in that model a signal is called using post_save and a mail function is called so. But I need id of that user from this model so that I can fetch his name,email_address from auth_user table.

I am sending the name of the model in post_save but i don't know how to use their fields in signals if possible.

right now I am using this code.

My model

```
class ABC(models.Model):
  .....
  .......

post_save.connect(handlers.model_saved, sender=ABC)
```

the signal which is called.

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail


def model_saved(sender, **kwargs):
    send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'from@example.com',
    ['ndhiman08@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
    print "SAVED",sender,kwargs
```

Terminal response

```
<class 'XYZ.models.ABC'> {'raw': False, 'instance': <ABC: #1 admin admin 2013-01-04 04:20:50+00:00>, 'signal': <django.dispatch.dispatcher.Signal object at 0xb612584c>, 'using': 'default', 'created': False}
```

Please suggest me some way so that i can use vales of my model fields in signals.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `instance` argument provided to signal handler which is the Model object saved.
So you can use it as :

```
def model_saved(sender, **kwargs):
    send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'from@example.com',
    ['ndhiman08@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
    abc_obj = kwargs['instance']
    #can use fields as 
    #abc_obj.somefield
    print "SAVED",sender,kwargs
```

[post_save documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) explains this.

Comment: Can we call a view function in handler.py..because when i am trying to import my view in handler.py it gives me internal server error.

Comment: @Inforian, Theoretically, yes but don't think practically you can do that as you would not have `request` and other parameters in signal handler.

Comment: yes it is because of request parameter but I resolve this issue by making another function without request